# Failed OPTIMIZE TABLE on InnoDB : "Got error 66 "Object is remote" from storage engine InnoDB"

Tags: mysql, mariadb, innodb

I have a InnoDB table:

```
Name            awesome_tbl
Engine          InnoDB
Version         10
Row_format      Compact
Rows            464
Avg_row_length  739469
Data_length     343113728
Max_data_length 0
Index_length    32768
Data_free       8388608
Auto_increment  618
Create_time     2020-09-02 13:34:37
Update_time     NULL
Check_time      NULL
Collation       cp1250_general_ci


MariaDB Version: 10.0.35-MariaDB
innodb_version: 5.6.39-83.1
```

When I run : `OPTIMIZE TABLE awesome_tbl;`

I get following messages:

```
Table       test.awesome_tbl
Op          optimize
Msg_type    note
Msg_text    Table does not support optimize, doing recreate + analyze instead


Table       test.awesome_tbl
Op          optimize
Msg_type    error
Msg_text    Got error 66 "Object is remote" from storage engine InnoDB

Table       test.awesome_tbl
Op          optimize
Msg_type    status
Msg_text    Operation failed
```

What the error 66 "Object is remote" means? What causes it? Google do not explains anything.

Thanx

Comment: Is your datadir or log file on a remote volume (for example, NFS or SMB)?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but your version of [MariaDB was end-of-life as of March 2019](https://mariadb.org/mariadb-55-rip/). You should upgrade, or else you're at risk of security vulnerabilities that will never be fixed.

Comment: @BillKarwin I do not know.... I can perform OPTIMIZE TABLE on other tables, but this one is problem. I can check tomorrow, if there is log file, but to tell the truth I doubt, that database tables are divided on different volumes...
Btw. thanks for unrelated note... :-)

Comment: I have also seen this error mentioned when the problem was that the redo log file was too small for some large BLOB/TEXT data. In those cases, reconfiguring a larger `innodb_log_file_size` was the solution. But I have no idea how that problem manifested in "error 66: Object is remote," which is an OS error.

Comment: In general `OPTIMIZE TABLE` is not worth doing on InnoDB tables.  Simply stop trying to Optimize any of your tables.